# Python & Selenium - how do I find all element IDs on a page?

Tags: python, selenium

I know that I can use methods such as:

```
find_elements_by_tag_name()
find_elements_by_id()
find_elements_by_css_selector()
find_elements_by_xpath()
```

But what I would like to do is simply get a list of all the element IDs that exist in the page, perhaps along with the tag type they occur in.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Arran's answer is great, but if you want speed, then you can get the page source, and parse it for ids.  This will take more coding than Arran's answer though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not had to do this before, but thinking about it logically you could use XPath to do this (may be other ways, XPath is the first thing that appears into my head).

Use `find_elements_by_xpath` using the XPath `//*[@id]` (**any** element that has an ID of some sort).

You could then iterate through the collection, and use the `.tag_name` property of each element to find out what *kind* of element it is and the `get_attribute("id")` method/function to get that element's ID.

Note: This is probably going to be quite slow. After all, you are asking for *a lot* of information.

Answer (score 48):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://google.com')

ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')
for ii in ids:
    #print ii.tag_name
    print ii.get_attribute('id')    # id name as string
```

Answer (score 5):

update for the excellent answer provided by russian_spy for new version of selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
ids = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id]')
# to get names use '//*[@name]'

for ii in ids:
    print('Tag: ' + ii.tag_name)
    print('ID: ' + ii.get_attribute('id'))     # element id as string
    print('Name: ' + ii.get_attribute('name')) # element name as string
```

Comment: To handle elements without names, consider str(ii.get_attribute('name')), which will print "None" instead of throwing a TypeError in your print() statement.

Comment: mysteryegg, thank you for pointing out!